# How do I isolate distinct data that occurs on the same date?

Tags: mysql

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| ORDERID | LOGCODE | EXDATE     |
+---------+---------+------------+
| 4970557 | 7462    | 2017-09-06 |
| 4970557 | 7462    | 2017-10-18 |
| 4970557 | 7462    | 2017-11-12 |
| 4970557 | 7462    | 2017-12-14 |
| 4970557 | 5691    | 2018-01-08 |
| 4970557 | 0244    | 2018-01-18 |
| 4970557 | 5691    | 2018-01-26 |
| 4970557 | 7462    | 2018-02-08 |
| 4970557 | 7462    | 2018-02-16 |
| 4970557 | 0026    | 2018-02-22 |
| 4970557 | 4344    | 2018-02-22 |
| 4970557 | 7462    | 2018-02-23 |
| 4970557 | 0026    | 2018-03-23 |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

I need to figure out a way to isolate 2 different logcodes that occur on the same day. In the example data above, this would be the two rows that occur on 2018-02-22, as well as their distinct logcodes. The rest can be ignored.

I have tried to isolate them with group by clauses, the count() method I found in other answers, and some having clauses, but I can't seem to figure out how to pull that specific information without it removing some of the logcode info I need or just grouping them into unusable information.

Admittedly I am new with MYSQL, and perhaps I am overlooking an obvious solution. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think that the question is not really clear. You want to query the rows for a given date? Or are you trying to find rows which have the same date and log code?

Comment: I need to isolate any instance where two distinct logcodes are issued to the same order on the same date.

The "group_concav" method seems to do the trick, though I was unable to work the "join" method out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the distinct rows you can join the table to itself and supply a `WHERE` condition like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mytable` t1
    JOIN `mytable` t2 USING (`EXDATE`)
WHERE t1.LOGCODE != t2.LOGCODE
```

If you want single rows with both `LOGCODE` values you can do it like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`LOGCODE`) as LOGCODES, `ORDERID`, `EXDATE`
FROM `mytable`
GROUP BY `EXDATE`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```